# How to access values from cached user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

There are 2 user controls(**Test1.ascx** and **Test2.ascx**). *Test1.ascx contains Test2.ascx.*

The inner user control(**Test2.ascx**) html is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test2.ascx.cs"
Inherits="Test.UserControls.Test2" %>

<%@ OutputCache Duration="200" VaryByParam="None" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<telerik:RadTreeView runat="server" ID="radTreeView" >
<DataBindings>
    <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding Depth="0" CssClass="rootNode" />
</DataBindings>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

The  outer user control(**Test1.ascx**) html is like:

```
<div runat="server" id="divTreeViewContainer">
        <uc:ucTreeView runat="server" ID="ucTreeView" />
    </div>
```

When first time the page is requested, both the user controls are loading perfectly. 
The tree view from Test2.ascx is accessed by FindControl() in Test1.ascx as

```
  //Find the tree view from the Test2.ascx user control
  var radTreeView = ucTreeView.FindControl("radTreeView") as RadTreeView;
```

From 2nd page request on-wards(i.e after inner user control Test2.ascx is cached) the  **ucTreeView** is coming as **null**.

**Requirement:**
The Test2.ascx user control needs to be cached and the control values of this user control will be accessed with in Test1.ascx user control(both in cached and non-cached condition). How to do it?

Lots of thanks in advance.